# Reopen queue versus edited posts not working properly?

Tags: bug, review, re-open

Recent comments have indicated that a question that gets edited after being put on hold should appear in the queue for reopen votes; I vaguely recall it was even said that a single reopen vote should work in this case, but I am unsure about that recollection.

I have recently stumbled across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707370/find-the-area-of-the-indicated-surface), which was closed 30 minutes ago, and edited 10 minutes ago to better narrow down what parts of the problem the questioner is having trouble with.

I voted to reopen directly. Then I thought to check the reopen queue: it doesn't appear, nor does my vote to reopen appear in the history.

I suppose that's fine since I've already voted to reopen but didn't do so through the review queue: do others see this question in the review queue for reopen votes?

Comment: It's in my reopen queue currently. It's currently been reviewed by [three users](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/177587) through the queues.

Comment: Ah, that's good; so it seems to be working as intended, although my recollection about a quick reopen being possible in this case seems to be in error. It's unfortunate that direct votes don't get put into the history, although it's probably not worth making a feature request over it.

Comment: The question was reopened; it took 5 votes as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions need 5 reopen votes to be reopened, whether they are on-hold or closed. The difference amounts to the criteria for putting the question into Reopen queue. [According to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/251274), in the on-hold phase (5 days) it suffices to the question to be

- Edited (body edits only) by the author, or
- Edited (body edits only) by a 3rd party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it.